# Prolog: Recognize a^n b^(n+1) language for n >= 1

Tags: prolog, clpfd

I understand that I need to figure out my own homework, but seeing that noone in the class can figure it out, I need some help.

> Write a Prolog program such that `p(X)`
>   is true if `X` is a list consisting of `n`
>   `a`'s followed by `n+1` `b`'s, for any `n >= 1`.

Comment: Ask the teacher. And if truly nobody understands it, the problem lies in the teaching, and you need to bring it up with your teacher.

Comment: @Neil Butterwork: As I recall, the `!` is the cut symbol which I think prevents backtracking. Can't remember what happens if you put a bunch of them together.

Comment: Is the problem your target language or the logic required to perform this? However, Gman is correct. Assuming your paying for this education you should reach out to the professor or TA 1st.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a counter to keep track of what you have found so far. When you find an `b`, add one to the counter. When you find a `a`, subtract one. The final value of your counter after the whole list is traversed should be one, since you want the number of `b`'s to be 1 more than the number of `a`'s. Here's an example of how to write that in code:

```
% When we see an "a" at the head of a list, we decrement the counter.
validList([a|Tail], Counter) :-
  NewCounter is Counter - 1,
  validList(Tail, NewCounter).

% When we see an "b" at the head of a list, we increment the counter.
validList([b|Tail], Counter) :-
  NewCounter is Counter + 1,
  validList(Tail, NewCounter).

% When we have been through the whole list, the counter should be 1.
validList([], 1).

% Shortcut for calling the function with a single parameter.
p(X) :-
  validList(X, 0).
```

Now, this will do *almost* what you want - it matches the rules for all `n >= 0`, while you want it for all `n >= 1`. In typical homework answer fashion, I've left that last bit for you to add yourself.

Comment: thanks, the homework was already due, I just wanted to know how to do it. My class is on Principles of Programming Languages, so we are being taught on things like Prolog and Ada but not being taught the language so it's kind of up to us to learn. So thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I don't remember how to code this in Prolog, but the idea is this:

Rule 1:
If listsize is 1, return true if the element is a B.

Rule 2:
If listsize is 2, return false.

Rule 3:
Check if the first item in the list is an A and the last one is a B.
If this is true, return the solution for elements 2 to listsize-1.

If I understood your problem correctly that should be the perfect Prolog style solution.

Edit: I totally forgot about this. I edited the answer to consider the case of n = 1 and n = 2. Thanks to Heath Hunnicutt.

Comment: This is a great answer.  It leaves out some cases, such as lists less than 2 characters long.  Adding the clauses for 0- and 1-item lists would make this answer the "perfect Prolog-style solution."

Comment: Yes, I forgot to add those rules. Thanks for telling me that, I will edit it in my post later (have to leave now).

Comment: Problem here is that checking the last item of a linked list is an O(n) operation, which is slow and does not have natural syntax. It is more in line with the logical declarative style, but unfortunately  in this particular case it's not something that Prolog encourages.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my abstruse solution

```
:-use_module(library(clpfd)).

n(L, N) -->
    [L],
    {N1 #= N-1
    },
    !, n(L, N1).
n(_, 0) --> [], !.

ab -->
    n(a, N),
    {N1 is N + 1
    },
    n(b, N1).

p(X) :- phrase(ab, X).

test :-
    p([b]),
    p([a,b,b]),
    p([a,a,b,b,b]),
    p([a,a,a,b,b,b,b]),
    \+ p([a]),
    \+ p([a,b]),
    \+ p([a,a,b,b]),
    \+ p([a,b,b,c]).
```

testing:

```
 ?- [ab].
% ab compiled 0.00 sec, -36 bytes
true.

 ?- test.
true.
```